# Защита роута beforeRouteEnter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Подскажите как можно запретить переход на соответствующий роут?
Проблема в том, что **beforeRouteEnter** не имеет доступа к **this**, так как к моменту его вызова навигация ещё не подтверждена, соответственно, и экземпляр компонента ещё не создан. Но доступ к экземпляру я получаю, передавая коллбэк в next

По коду ниже смысл в том, что если **user === null** выводится в консоль сообщение о необходимости зарегистрироваться или войти в профиль, если **user !== null**, то выводится сообщение 'success'. Но как мне именно запретить переход, а не только выводить сообщение о необходимости регистрации?

```
// Vuex

export default {
    state: {
        user: null,
    },
    getters: {
        login(state) {
            return state.user
        }
    }
}



//Bookmarks component

export default {
    computed: {
        checklogin() {
           return this.$store.getters.login;
        }
    },
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {

        next(vm => {
            if(vm.checklogin) {
                console.log('success');
            } else {
                console.log('Для перехода в избранное, необходимо зайти в ваш профиль или зарегистрироваться');
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую перечитать доку к [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#%D0%B3n%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). А если по делу, то после **console.log()** можно вызвать **next(from)** или **next(false)** и переход не произойдет.

Comment: Вы предлагаете в колбек метода next() вложить еще один next(false)? То что вы написали - не работает!

Comment: А в чем проблема заменить next(false) на vm.$router.go(-1)?

Comment: Вот вам пример набросал https://codesandbox.io/s/7w26p5nzpx

Comment: А вообще зачем вы в next проверку делаете? Не проще импортировать store и обращаться не к vm.checklogin, а к store.getters.login?

Comment: vm.$router.go(-1) - предполагает действие, это значит, что сначала произойдет переход на роут '/bookmarks', а затем произойдет переход назад - это неправильное поведение. Проверка происходит в колбеке next(), поскольку beforeRouteEnter не имеет доступа к this, так как к моменту его вызова навигация ещё не подтверждена, поскольку экземпляр компонента ещё не создан

Comment: Я все это отлично знаю ))) Я и спрашиваю - зачем такие сложности? Не проще импортировать store и обращаться не к vm.checklogin, а к store.getters.login, не вызывая next? Сходите по моей ссылке. Файл components/Profile.vue, 16 строка.

Comment: Все верно, можно в компонент bookmarks импортировать store и обратиться к store.getters.login, но ведь сам store уже импортирован в корневой экземпляр Vue. Поэтому во всех компонентах идет обращение к this.$store. Конечно, можно импортировать store в каждый компонент отдельно - вариант рабочий. Тут вопрос еще в чистоте кода и правильности его организации.

Comment: А у вас выхода нет другого )) До вызова next вы никак до this не доберетесь, а вызов next как раз инициирует разрешение роута.